# TikZ libraries in bookdown

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown

I'm building a file that will be compiled to PDF and HTML (gitbook and tufte style), and I'm trying to get my `tikzpicture` environments working. I've seen that I can include them as figures by using something like

````
```{r,echo=FALSE,engine='tikz',fig.ext=if (knitr:::is_latex_output()) 'pdf' else 'png'}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    CODE HERE
  \end{tikzpicture}
```,
````

but I haven't figured out how to include any extra TikZ libraries when doing this (which would be achieved for LaTeX output by including `\usetikzlibrary{decorations}`, for example, but in the *preamble*, not in the body (hence the difficulties)). How can I do this, or is it not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that you can simply put the `\usetikzlibrary{...}` command directly before the `\begin{tikzpicture}` and everything works fine :)